# PHP Serve 25 numbers in random order

Tags: php, arrays, random

I would like to serve an array of 25 elements randomly.
I'm not sure how to do this.

Say the array has numbers from 0 to 24.
I want to produce something like that:

```
5,4,6,7,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24,25,1,2,11,14,15... etc
```

So if the generator outputs 23 it should not output it again

Thanks

Comment: Are the elements of the array random as well, or are they predefined, and you only want them ordered randomly?

Comment: [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/function.shuffle), [`range()`](http://php.net/function.range)

Comment: After the array is shuffled you can use http://php.net/array-shift or http://php.net/array-pop to extract elements from the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$numbers = range(0, 24);
shuffle($numbers);

print_r($numbers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like

```
$array;
$shuffledArray = shuffle($array);
```

In your concrete example you are talking about to output a comma separated string of numbers from 0 to 24

```
echo implode(',', shuffle(range(0,24));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the array already, you can use the PHP function called `shuffle()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

if not, build the array like this:

```
<?php
    $max = 24;
    $num_array = array();
    for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++) $num_array[] = $i;
    shuffle($num_array);
?>
```

**Update:** I've never seen the range function used before (by KingCrunch). Much better to use that one!

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 25; ++$i) {
    $array[] = $i;
}
shuffle($array);
print_r($array);
```

The shuffle function is very useful in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = range(1,25);
shuffle($r);
var_dump($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$numbers = range(0, 24);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
echo "$number ";
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php